# CoffeeScript and Service Workers

Tags: coffeescript, service-worker

When trying to register a service worker in CoffeeScript, it looks like the latest Chrome browser doesn't support service workers, which I know is not true. Here is my app.coffee, which is converted to JavaScript and loaded on my web page:

```
registerServiceWorker = () =>
    if 'serviceWorker' in navigator
        await navigator.serviceWorker.register '/service-worker.js'
        console.log "Service Worker Registered"
    else
        console.log "No service worker support"

registerServiceWorker()
```

And here is the resulting JavaScript:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 2.7.0
(function() {
  var registerServiceWorker,
    indexOf = [].indexOf;

  registerServiceWorker = async() => {
    if (indexOf.call(navigator, 'serviceWorker') >= 0) {
      await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
      return console.log("Service Worker Registered");
    } else {
      return console.log("No service worker support");
    }
  };

  registerServiceWorker();

}).call(this);
```

The JavaScript console displays "No service worker support". My Chrome version is Version 111.0.5563.65 (Official Build) (64-bit). It's running on Windows 11.

As I suspected, if I change "if 'serviceWorker' in navigator" to "if navigator.serviceWorker", then everything works just fine. But, though I have a workaround, I'm beginning to wonder if it's safe to use "X in Y" in CoffeeScript. Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `of` instead of `in`.

This is probably a legacy thing, as coffeescript used `in` for array iteration and `of` for objects. These presence operators were made to match the existing iterator syntax, which makes it the opposite of the javascript of `in` for objects and `of` for arrays.

Personally I would use `if navigator?.serviceWorker` as the JS `in` doesn't check that the value isn't null or defined on a prototype.
In your usecase, these exceptions don't apply, so you are safe to use `in` if you prefer.

From the docs on [coffeescript.org](https://coffeescript.org/#operators):

> You can use in to test for array presence, and of to test for JavaScript object-key presence.
>
> ...
>
> `a in b` becomes `[].indexOf.call(b, a) >= 0`
>
> `a of b` becomes `a in b`